# Flutter - How to call functions (and variables) between stateful widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, parameter-passing

I have this function in a widget (homescreen):

```
void toggleRecording() async {

  // HERE IS THE CONFUSION I GUESS
  _isRecording = !_isRecording;
  recorder = SoundStream(isRecording: _isRecording);

  //recorder.toggleRecording(_isRecording);
  setState(() {
    _isRecording = recorder.isRecording;
  });
  if (_isRecording) {
    startTimer();
    _stopwatch.start();
  } else {
    stopTimer();
    _stopwatch.stop();
  }
}
```

It needs to call (trigger) another function in my recorder class:

```
void toggleRecording() async {

  widget.isRecording  ////// currently being passed as an argument from homescreen

      ? {_recorder.stop, await save(_micChunks, 44100)}
      : _recorder.start;
}
```

Also, the boolean variable `_isRecording` is present in both the classes. How do I sync the state?

Comment: This is a state management problem Try out provider or riverpod for starters, in which you can expose some state across multiple widgets.

Comment: I tried provider. Couldn't get everything working together.

Comment: Provider indeed is easy at the beginning, but it's kind-of hard to get everything to work altogether at some point. Try out Riverpod, that's the production-ready version of Provider in my opinion. Version 1.0 is coming soon~ish, too.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation passing reference of function through widgets will work. However best practice of this will be using [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Managing functions from provider will allow you to control functions from all pages.

If you change a variable you can call notifylistener() function inside your provider function. So that you can change state of widget.

I will try to explain it in a glance however this is an important subject of flutter.

Here is my folder structure

[image]

At provider folder we define our provider classes.

Firstly i define class which extends changeNotifier class. This is what make this class provider.

Side note: notifyListener() function here calls setState of every widget if you use any variables inside that class and this is what you are searching for.

[image]

Then i import it into my main.dart file or whatever file you want. Only condition is being above the widget that you will use provider at.

[image]

At last you can use your function at everywhere if you import provider package and define your provider like i did in this code.

[image]

At last here is the visualized stucture of provider package.

[image]

I wish i explained it well. There is more about it on youtube.

Comment: Can you please show some code example?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass the function to other widget 
using Function keyword


Say ContentWidget is your child and ParentWidget is parent

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {

//Do Something
void onSomeFunction()
{
ContentWidget(onTimerUpdate:onTimerClosed)

}

void onTimerClosed()
{
//Perform Operation on Timer Change
}



}

class ContentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 final Function onTimerUpdate;

ContentWidget({
 Key key,
 @required this.onTimerUpdate,
  }) : super(key: key);

void onAnyActionFromChild()
{
widget.onTimerUpdate() //Note () can have any param or can be null
}
```